# Symfony validation messages always in default locale

Tags: php, symfony, internationalization, symfony5

So I've configured a site to have several locales depending on the locale in the URL, for example:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/signup/es/
http://127.0.0.1:8000/signup/en/
```

I have a LocaleSubscriber, like this:

```
public function onKernelRequest(RequestEvent $event)
{
    $request = $event->getRequest();

    /* If first request */
    if (!$request->hasPreviousSession()) {
        /* Set locale in session (locale from URL) */
        // ...
    }

    return;
}
```

And this works fine for everything except **validation messages**.
Translations are stored like this:

```
/translations/messages.en.yaml
/translations/messages.es.yaml
/translations/validators.en.yaml
/translations/validators.es.yaml
```

The only thing I can see for sure is that whatever I set the default locale to over here:

```
/config/packages/translation.yaml
```

For example:

```
framework:
    default_locale: es
    translator:
        default_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/translations'
        fallbacks:
            - es
```

Then the validation messages will always be in **that** locale, in this case **ES**.
All other translations work fine.
Am I missing something here?
It looks like translations aren't configured to use the session '_locale' variable or something like this.
Any ideas?

EDIT:
Added route config:

```
 * @Route(
 *      "/signup/{_locale}/",
 *      locale="en",
 *      requirements={
 *         "_locale": "en|fr|de|es|it"
 *      },
 *      name="signup",
 *      methods={"GET"}
 * )
```

EDIT:
The kernel request body should look like this for it to work:

```
if ($locale = $request->attributes->get('_locale')) {
    $request->getSession()->set('_locale', $locale);
} else {
    $request->setLocale($request->getSession()->get('_locale', $this->defaultLocale));
    }
```

So the session _locale variable wasn't updating as expecting on each request.
Thanks guys for helping me troubleshoot it!

Comment: 5.2? it's not released yet. Did you mean 5.2-dev? btw, the latest version is 5.1 (released today :) ). I need the exact version you're using to be able to reproduce the issue correctly.

Comment: I would check what locale your request and session holds right before validation occurs, something might not be correctly set there. (that's all I can say, apart from clearing the cache, which you've probably already done anyway)

Comment: @yceruto According to composer: "symfony/framework-bundle": "5.0.*", and I believe it's 5.0.8

Comment: try with `composer show` or `php bin/console about` commands, there you'll see the extact Symfony version, I will look at this later

Comment: About your issue, Symfony already have a LocaleListener that configures the current locale through the `_locale` attribute. Can you show the Route configuration for those paths?

Answer (score 0):

If you have added a listener to the kernel response, make sure it runs before the other listeners by giving it a priority that is higher. The default priority is 0, i.e. run last.

I had the same problem as you had and solved it by changing the priority of the kernel listener to 127.